# Install Eclipse Oxygen on Ubuntu 16.04 Certificate Problem

Tags: software-installation, eclipse, certificates, eclipse-cdt

I tried to install Eclipse Oxygen using the Oomph installer contained in the download.

However during the installation process it asks whether i trust two certificates.

[image]

When I clicked on details it said

[image]

So as far as I can see (since it says Valid Until: 14. April 2012) the certificate is not valid anymore and thus I deduced that a not valid certificate should not be trusted (unless I have a good reason to do that). The validity date of the second one is the same by the way.

**My question:**

Should these certificates be trusted? If not or unclear, then is there a different way to get Eclipse Oxygen on my system?

Comment: You can always download a full zip file like in the old days from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/

Comment: This would be fine, if I could just download the source and then configure; make; make install, but I don't see any possibility for that at the moment.